# How correctly map and reduce json value "uppercase"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

currently i have an json

```js
const translations = [{
  "fr": {
    "A.A.B_B": "salut",
    "example": "example",
  },
  "en": {
    "A.A.B_B": "Hi",
    "example": "example",
  },
}]

// then I map
const lg = "fr";
const filterLg = translations.map((e) => e[lg]);

// then I reduce for to delete the table

const t = filterLg.reduce(
  (accumulator, value) => ({ ...accumulator, value }), {}
);

console.log(t)
```

this works correctly.

my problem and the next one

this does not work

```
   console.log(t.value.A.A.B_B);
```

but this yes

```
console.log(t.value.example);
```

iam open to any proposal thank you very much.

thx Neff

Comment: It has one key, `"A.A.B_B"`, so `console.log(t.value["A.A.B_B"])` would work. `t.value.A.A.B_B` tries to access the key `A`, with a sub-key `A` with another sub-key `B_B`.

Comment: Also, if there are multiple objects in `translations`, the code `({ ...accumulator, value })` will only keep the last object from the array.